# SAS: group rows into different datasets by condition

Tags: sql, sas

favorite
I need to create 7 datasets (`local`, `web`, `call`, `local&call`, `local&web`, `call&web`, `all`) depending on if the customer has used a channel from the below sample data.

```
| customer | call | local | web |
|----------|------|-------|-----|
|     1    |   1  |   1   |  1  |
|     1    |      |   1   |  1  |
|     1    |      |   1   |     |
|     2    |   1  |       |  1  |
|     2    |      |   1   |     |
|     2    |   1  |       |     |
|     3    |      |       |  1  |
|     3    |   1  |   1   |     |
```

[please see this picture for more details on the sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAIMp.png)

So if a customer has used all three channels in one instance and in the other instance he just uses either of them, then that row with Customer=1 should go to the'all' dataset. Similarly for 3, if he has used local and web in one instance and just web in another instance, then it should go to the `local&web` dataset.

Customer IDs should not be duplicated in other dataset i.e. customer 1 can belong to wither one of the dataset only.

I am stuck with this, can anyone give me a snippet of either sas or sql code to proceed further.

Thanks !

Comment: `case when max(call) = 1 then 1 else 0 end + case when max(local) = 1 then 2 else 0 end + case when max(web) = 1 then 4 else 0 end` This is a SQL approach as I know very little about SAS.

Comment: Please post sample data in the post, not as an image, and include what the expected output should be. Why are you creating separate datasets? In SAS, this is rarely a good idea, you can use BY groups further on to process data more efficiently than if in multiple datasets.

Comment: Don't all 3 in your sample go to 'ALL'?

Comment: Hey Reeza you are right,  all the 3 customers should go to ALL. Can you help me in getting a query for that. 
So for all the 3 instances of customer =1, I should ahve only one record with "ALL" as new column.

Comment: Aggregate so you only have 1 row per customer, use SQL or proc means. Then write a bunch of if statements to create groups.

Answer (score 0):

If all three go to "all", then use aggregation:

```
select customer,
       (case when max(call) > 0 and max(local) > 0 and max(web) > 0 then 'all'
             else concat_ws('&', (case when max(call) > 0 then 'call' end),
                            (case when max(local) > 0 then 'local' end),
                            (case when max(web) > 0 then 'web' end)
                           )
        end) as grp
from t
group by customer;
```

Comment: Hey Godron, how would you write it for this scenario - 'customer1' has first instance of (call,local,web) as (0,1,1) and second instance as (0,0,1)
In this case, I want it to go to 'local_web' only....

Comment: @newbie49 . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not as comments.